# keras 2.02 to keras 2.12: code no longer working

Tags: keras, theano

I am building a convolution net with multiple sizes of filters. The code is shown below, which works before in keras 2.0.2 with theano 0.9. I recently migrated to keras 2.1.2 with theano 1.0.1, and it is no longer working. and I do not understand the error that the last line is throwing

```python
flts=100
kernel_sizes=[2,3,4]
submodels = []
embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=100, output_dim=300,
                                input_length=100)
for kw in kernel_sizes:    # kernel sizes
    submodel = Sequential()
    submodel.add(embedding_layer)
    submodel.add(Dropout(0.2))
    submodel.add(Conv1D(filters=flts,
                        kernel_size=kw,
                        padding='same',
                        activation='relu'))
    submodel.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=kw))
    submodels.append(submodel)

submodel_outputs = [model.output for model in submodels]
x = Concatenate(axis=1)(submodel_outputs)
parallel_layers=Model(inputs=embedding_layer.input, outputs=x) ### error at this line
```

The last line generates an error with keras 2.1.2, and previously it was working:

```python
  File "...", line 137, in ...
    parallel_layers=Model(inputs=embedding_layer.input, outputs=x)
  File "/home/ziqizhang/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 926, in input
    ' has multiple inbound nodes, '
AttributeError: Layer embedding_1 has multiple inbound nodes, hence the notion of "layer input" is ill-defined. Use `get_input_at(nod                                                                e_index)` instead.
```

I would really appreciate some tips on how to correct this, many thanks!

Comment: I don't think combining the functional API with the Sequential one like you are doing is correct. You should use the functional API for everything in your model.

Comment: thanks for the comment. the problem is that i really want to use the KerasClassifier that wraps around scikit learn, so I can use gridsearch on it. I remember i started with functional API but then did not know where to go in order to implement this, and therefore fall back on this method...

Comment: you can still use the wrapper with the functional API.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the same `Embedding` layer instance to each sub-model, that's why it has multiple inputs (it has the input layer of each sub-model as its input), and that is in turn why `embedding_layer.input` is ambiguous. Do this instead:

```
for kw in kernel_sizes:    # kernel sizes
    embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim=100, output_dim=300,
                                input_length=100)
    submodel = Sequential()
    submodel.add(embedding_layer)
    submodel.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

(i.e. create the `Embedding` layer instance inside the loop)